# Pull SQL data by Session Login

Tags: php

I'm attempting to pull SQL data. A user's login is their username, but I don't want that displayed to any other users. Hence the nicename I have defined. It's another display name that has nothing to do with a users login info; When I try to send a message I want the from field to display their display name; does anyone know why this ends up sending no data through the query in the from field?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$webdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE name=$_SESSION['admin_login']";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$display_name = $row['nicename'];
{
echo '<input name="from" type="hidden" value="' .$display_name.'">';
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Alright, so I ran the query and fixed the display name variable; When I the query I recieve.

```
INSERT INTO messages (`owner`, `from`, `content`, `date`, `title`) VALUES ('Morgan', '', 'Query', 'Oct/16/2012', 'Testing The ')
```

The From variable is still displaying nothing;
I added a debug page to my site where I put in my query as

```
$query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE username=$_SESSION[admin_login]";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I then echoed my query and also echoed $row[nicename] Where I receive back on the page:
SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE username=****<--It did add my username;
however the echo on $row[nicename] returns no results on the page.

```
{
echo $query;//<--Returns Query with the correct login variable.
echo '<br>';
echo $row['nicename'];//<--Returns no info.
}
```

Comment: You may have to edit your query like $query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE name='$_SESSION['admin_login']'";

putting your session variable in quotes as it is a string comparision.

Comment: And $display_name = $row['nicename']; please!

Answer (score 2):

**Change this:**

```
$display_name = $row['title'];
```

**To this:**

```
$display_name = $row['nicename'];
```

- I always prefer to use normal PHP variables instead of session variables in my SQL statements. This can avoid confusion with data types.

  $username = $_SESSION['admin_login'];
  $query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE name = '$username'";

Another example:

```
$chatroomNumber = intval($_SESSION['chatroomid']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE chatroomnumber = $chatroomNumber";
```

This ensures that you are using a int in the SQL statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't fix it. However storing session data into a PHP var is not a bad idea at all. Thanks for that input.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging with the help of people here spotting errors my query ended up being:

```
$query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE username='$_SESSION[admin_login]'";
```

With my from input on the form being

```
echo '<input name="from" type="hidden" value="' .$display_name.'">';
```

And $display_name defined as $row['nicename'] These settings displayed the Display name in the From field and kept the login name hidden. Thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what that `$_SESSION['admin_login']` contains, you'll likely want to quote it:

```
$query = 'SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE name="' . $_SESSION['admin_login'] . '"';
```

Comment: That's a typo, but I did put the same typo in my actual page, Going to correct that; thanks. I've read over it countless time and haven't noticed that.

Comment: On the query have it as `code`"SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable WHERE yourothercolumn='$_SESSION[admin_login]'"`code` In case you ever hit the same issue. I had tried it the way you had posted and it actually entered $_SESSION[admin_login] into my column which isn't really what was being attempted. Just hoping that I'm not the only one who ever hits this issue and it helps someone else out.

Comment: I had wrote this in my answer - That you should store your session variables into normal PHP variables before using them in SQL statements. It avoids this/similar problems . E.g. $chatroomNumber =  intval($_SESSION['chatroomid']); - This ensures that you are using a number in the SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

First check the source code of the from in your browser to check it's creating the hidden input with the correct value.

If the hidden is fine, check what the PHP file that processes the form receives (print_r($_POST) could help).

If it's getting the value then check how you are building the SQL query.

Posting some more code could give us a better idea of where the problem might be.